# Android studio:Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new in android studio.I have created a simple application "Setting up Face book SDK in Android Studio" application but in this when I tried to run then I Face this problem that is

> Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed.
>   Error:Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

and also another issue that is:

> Error running app: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem with the error tip:

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener

the reason is that: project compile depend on each other directly or indirectly.for example, A compile with B， B compile with A